# Getting org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException while accessing a URL from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, selenium, browserstack

We are using BrowserStack for a project.

The portal we are testing is whitelisted for our IP.

And we access internet behind proxy.

While running below code snippet:

```
public class DemoClass {

public static final String USERNAME = "<Username>";
public static final String AUTOMATE_KEY = "<Key>";
public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY 
+ "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 String baseUrl;
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("browser", "IE");
caps.setCapability("browser_version", "7.0");
caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
caps.setCapability("os_version", "XP");
caps.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");
caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "<Proxy URL>");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "<Proxy Port>");
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
....
```

We are getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a 
new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or 
browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: '<HOSTNAME>', ip: '<HOST IP>', os.name: 'Windows 
7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
at demopackage.DemoClass.main(DemoClass.java:31)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to hub-
cloud.browserstack.com:443 [hub-cloud.browserstack.com/5.255.92.202] failed: 
Connection refused: connect
.........
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please consider updating me the Selenium version you are using? Thanks

Comment: It looks like the proxy details you mentioned did not help. I noticed you have specified the Hub URL as HTTPS. Have you tried switching to HTTP and check if it works? Lastly, you can also try doing a cURL to the Hub URL as follows: curl -x<HOSTNAME>:<PORT> -L https://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/status. Try both HTTP and HTTPS. This will help confirm if you are able to connect to BrowserStack's Selenium Hub.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I din't find any significant issue in your code block as such. But here are a few points you need to take care:

1. When you do `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);` remember to `import java.net.URL;`
2. I have observed you handling the base exception as `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception` rather you may consider to be precise by `public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException`
3. You mentioned `We are using BrowserStack for a project` but you haven't mentioned whether you are using `BrowserStack Automation` or  `BrowserStack Running local tests`.
4. Assuming you are using `BrowserStack Automation` you need to remove `caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");` from your code.
5. Incase you are using `BrowserStack Running local tests` you need to mention `caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");` in your code.
6. Assuming you are using `BrowserStack Automation`, here is your own code block along with some simple tweaks which successfully executes on "BrowserStack Automation":

   ```
   package SeleniumGrid;

   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

   import java.net.MalformedURLException;
   import java.net.URL;

   public class Q44196893_IE_BrowserStack {

   public static final String USERNAME = "<Username>";
   public static final String AUTOMATE_KEY = "<Key>";
   public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";


   public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {


        String baseUrl;
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("browser", "IE");
        caps.setCapability("browser_version", "7.0");
        caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
        caps.setCapability("os_version", "XP");
        caps.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "<Proxy URL>");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "<Proxy Port>");
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
        driver.get("http://google.com/");
        System.out.println("Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();

   }

   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Set your proxy in `_JAVA_OPTIONS` under system variables and it will start working. I faced the same issue and it get resolved by providing proxy for both http and https for `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.